# How do I set up dependency injection if my concrete class requires simple data type in addition to other interface(s)?

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

If I have a class structure like below:

```
public interface IDataProvider
{
    object GetSomeData(int id);
}

public class InMemoryDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    public InMemoryDataProvider(string connString)
    {

    }

    public object GetSomeData(int id)
    {
        return new object();
    }
}

public interface IAnimal
{
    string GetName();
}

public class Dog: IAnimal
{
    public Dog(string someRequiredInfo, IDataProvider someDataProvider)
    {

    }
    public string GetName()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

I am trying to set up DI chain using default DI container that comes with asp.net core MVC. But I don't understand how to set up for my scenario. I am new to using DI container so I could be missing some fundamental idea.Below is how I tried to set it up (unsuccessfully):

```
string connString = "connectionString";
someString = "some required info";
AddSingleton<IDataProvider, InMemoryDataProvider>(x => new InMemoryDataProvider(connString));
AddTransient<IAnimal, Dog>(); //if I do this, how will it get the first parameter of someString? Don't think this will even work.
AddTransient<IAnimal, Dog>(x => new Dog(someString, IDataProvider???)) //how to do this?
```

Also, I want the data provider to be a singleton and that eliminates the possibility of doing like below isn't it?

```
services.AddTransient<IAnimal, Dog>(x => new Dog(someString, new InMemoryDataProvider(connString)));
```

Comment: What DI is it using by default?

Comment: It asp.net core mvc has its own built in container and I am using that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your code in yout Startup.cs to the snippet below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddSingleton(x => new InMemoryDataProvider(connString));
            services.AddSingleton<IDataProvider, InMemoryDataProvider>(x => x.GetService<InMemoryDataProvider>());
            services.AddSingleton<IAnimal, Dog>(d=> new Dog(someString, d.GetService<IDataProvider>()));

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

And just inject IAnimal into your Controllers constructor like so:

```
public ValuesController(IAnimal animal)
        {
            _animal = animal;          
        }
```